# cv2.createTrackbar parameter not updated in the callback function

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement a trackbar that allows to scale up and down an image. In the exercise, there are two trackbars: the first trackbar deals with the scale factor while the second deals with if it increases or decreases the scale of the image. The first trackbar seems to work, since I can play around with increasing the size of the image(scaleFactor). However, the second trackbar does not update the value (scaleType) within the function and therefore it does not change the mode to downscale the image.

I think the error is in the way I pass the variable into the function since the documentation and the example of the first trackbar are quite straightforward.

This is the code:

```
import cv2


maxScaleUp = 100
scaleFactor = 1
scaleType = 0
maxType = 1

windowName = "Resize Image"
trackbarValue = "Scale"
trackbarType = "Type: \n 0: Scale Up \n 1: Scale Down"


# load an image
im = cv2.imread("truth.png")

# Create a window to display results
cv2.namedWindow(windowName, cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

# Callback functions
def scaleImage(*args):
    global scaleFactor
    global scaleType


    if scaleType == 0:

        scaleFactor = 1+ args[0]/100.0
        if scaleFactor == 0:
            scaleFactor = 1
        scaledImage = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=scaleFactor,\
                fy = scaleFactor, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    else:       
        scaleFactor = 1 - args[0]/100.0
        if scaleFactor == 0:
            scaleFactor = 1
        scaledImage = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=scaleFactor,\
                fy = scaleFactor, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    print(scaleType)
    cv2.imshow(windowName, scaledImage)

def functionType( *args):
    return 0



cv2.createTrackbar(trackbarValue, windowName, scaleFactor, maxScaleUp, scaleImage)
cv2.createTrackbar(trackbarType, windowName, scaleType, maxType, functionType)


scaleImage(25)

while True:
    c = cv2.waitKey(20)

    if c==27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to do the job. Basically have two callback functions that take the argument and update the variable.

```
import cv2


maxScaleUp = 100
scaleFactor = 1
scaleType = 0
maxType = 1

windowName = "Resize Image"
trackbarValue = "Scale"
trackbarType = "Type: \n 0: Scale Up \n 1: Scale Down"


# load an image
im = cv2.imread("truth.png")

# Create a window to display results
cv2.namedWindow(windowName, cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

# Callback functions
def scaleImage(*args):
    global scaleFactor
    global scaleType


    if scaleType == 0:

        scaleFactor = 1+ args[0]/100.0
        if scaleFactor == 0:
            scaleFactor = 1
        scaledImage = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=scaleFactor,\
                fy = scaleFactor, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    else:       
        scaleFactor = 1 - args[0]/100.0
        if scaleFactor == 0:
            scaleFactor = 1
        scaledImage = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=scaleFactor,\
                fy = scaleFactor, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    print(scaleType)
    cv2.imshow(windowName, scaledImage)

def functionType( *args):
    global scaleType
    global scaleFactor
    scaleType = args[0]
    scaleFactor = 1 + scaleFactor/100.0
    if scaleFactor ==0:
        scaleFactor = 1
    scaledImage = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=scaleFactor,\
            fy = scaleFactor, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    cv2.imshow(windowName, scaledImage)


cv2.createTrackbar(trackbarValue, windowName, scaleFactor, maxScaleUp, scaleImage)
cv2.createTrackbar(trackbarType, windowName, scaleType, maxType, functionType)
```